# ArcPy script using 'symbology.addAllValues()' failing

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, symbology

I'm having a problem trying to use `symbology.addAllValues()` on a layer with Unique Values Symbology. Unfortunately, I can't paste in actual code here since the machine I'm working on is classified, but essentially I am trying to do this:

```python
source.symbology.valueField = "Name"    
source.symbology.addAllValues()
```

it is failing with an error "in addAllValues return convertArcObjectToPythonObject ..."

The funny thing is that if I manually go into Arc and tell it to add all values, then run my script, it doesn't give the error.

Is addAllValues expecting a table of the values to already exist so it can update it, and it is choking because it doesn't find it?

Comment: Even though your code is classified, in order for us to be able to help you with this, we will need you to develop a code snippet using unclassified code that produces the same error, so that you can present that precise code and error message here.